# Matplotlib.pyplot.bar seems to produce incorrect results

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a little bar chart in matplotlib, but something don't look right:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10) 

print(bins) # = [0. 0.11 0.22 0.33 0.44 0.55 0.66 0.77 0.88 1.]

plt.bar(bins, bins)
```

[image]

I expect a staircase from 0:1 on both axes -- am I missing something? Any suggestions would be helpful!

I'm on matplotlib 3.0.3:

```
pip freeze | grep matplotlib
# returns matplotlib==3.0.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `plt.bar`, the bar width is default at <strike>`1`</strike> `0.8` (thanks @Cohan), so the bars overlap each other, as you can see in your picture with the last bar.

Change to `plt.bar(bins, bins, width=0.1)` yields:

[image]

Comment: ah, thanks! That seems pretty janky design to me -- the min of the bar widths would probably be a better default. I'll accept this once SO lets me...

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html says the width default is 0.8, but your answer is still the correct explanation.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers points out the problem, you might be interesting in knowing that you can adjust the width according to the number of data points as following rather than specifying it manually.

P. S: The formula `width = 1.0/(len(bins) + 1)` is a better choice **especially** when your data ranges between 0 and 1.See below for a general formula.  The constant `+1` in the denominator while computing width is a matter of choice. You can as well choose 2, 3, and so on to make the width thinner.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10) 
width = 1.0/(len(bins) + 1)

plt.bar(bins, bins, width=width)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To make it more general, I came up with this formula. This will work even if you your data is beyond 0 and 1

```
width = (max(bins) - min(bins)) * 1.0/(len(bins) + 1)
```

Comment: This is a better answer because more general. Can you see a good reason why matplotlib wouldn't do this (or use the min bin width as the width for all bars) by default?

Comment: @duhaime: Check my edit to the answer. You are here plotting only between 0 and 1, so the formula in the answer works well. If you use `np.linspace(0, 10, 10) ` instead, you will see the width becomes like a line. Of course, I think one can make it more general by multiplying with the extent of the data. I am not sure why this is not the default.